# is that right - windows 7

Tags: windows-7

a friend has comed to me with a windows 7 setup dvd.

he told me that it is free to use until march 2010. is this right? what it will happen after that date?

If i install now windows 7 in march i have to go back to vista if i don't wana buy the win7 version or what?

Comment: You should probably accept MrStatic's answer, which is near identical, and posted 1 hour earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He probably gave you a copy of the RC version of windows 7 [this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd353205.aspx) will give you more info.

Answer (score 2):

You have most probably been given a RC version of Windows 7, which expires on March 2010. If by then you don't purchase and install the release version of Windows 7 then you will have to go back to Windows Vista.

[image: winver]